# How to prompt connecting another wallet via Web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm building a dapp that allows users to connect multiple wallets. When a user is not connected to my app at all and I issue the `const accounts = await this.eth.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });` call, MetaMask pops up the connect dialog as expected. However, if a user is already connected with a different wallet I am unable to get that to pop up again on MetaMask so the user can authorize the connection additional wallets. Is there a programmatic way to get MetaMask to display the connect dialog so the user can add the wallet they currently have selected in MetaMask?